# How I get text from the tr, having two separate div on condition

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rh9iU.jpg)this is booking application, when I click any date, I want to get text "available sets" from that cell, here date "11" is in div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Gdup.jpg) and text is under div[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBAXd.jpg) so I create dynamic xpath for available text and how I get text based of providing date.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBAXd.jpg)

Comment: Can you format the question with relevant HTML in text format? Also the code that you've tried so far and where are you stuck in that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but unfortunately not working for me :(,

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question correctly, you'd like to find the day content div text based on a date parameter. If so, it can be achieved like this:

`//div[@class='fc-day-number'][text()='11']/following-sibling::div[@class='fc-day-content]`

Then in your code, it would look something like the below with the parameterised day, and calling the `getText()` function...I'll use java in this example...

```
public String getDayContent(int dayNumber){
    return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='fc-day-number'][text()='"+dayNumber+"']/following-sibling::div[@class='fc-day-content]")).getText();
}
```

You'll have to test it to make sure it works, as it's difficult to test the xpath without having access to the website, but if you have any problems let me know